# Toggle switch does not work in PartialView

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have partial view , that I use in View

In this partialView I have toggle switch

Here is css file of this switch

```
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

And here is code in partialView where this toggle is

```
<div id="switcher" class="doctors-appointment">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Column">
            <b>Doctor's appointment</b>
        </div>

        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="Column">
            <b>For internal purposes</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem in that toggle is rendering great, but when I click it, it doesn't animate.

Where can be trouble?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is snippet same of your code it is animating.

Look This snippet i think there is a something other `css` which is conflicting with your switch `css`.

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="switcher" class="doctors-appointment">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Column">
            <b>Doctor's appointment</b>
        </div>

        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="Column">
            <b>For internal purposes</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. I will search for conflicts